# Microsoft SOAP Toolkit 2.0のダウンロード

Tags: webapi, soap, vb6

Microsoft SOAP Toolkit 2.0をダウロードできるリンクを教えて下さい。
iis5、VB6の環境でWebサービス(SOAP)を構築したいです。
実装例やiis5への設定方法が載ったページもあれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のサイトの「サブスクライバーアクセス」からたどっていって入手できると思われます。
[Visual Studio: ソフトウェア開発者とチーム向けのIDEおよびコードエディター](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ja/)

ただし、以下の条件が必要でしょう。

- Visual StudioまたはMSDNのしかるべき製品またはライセンスを購入していること。
  その種類によっては入手出来ないものもあるでしょう。
- Microsoftアカウントを登録してサインインしていること。
- 上記サイトのサブスクライバーとして登録していること。

このサイトとページから始まる一連の記事が提供しているサービスと使い方の説明になっています。
[Visual Studio サブスクリプションに関するドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/subscriptions/)

[サブスクライバー ポータルの使用 - my.visualstudio.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/subscriptions/using-the-subscriber-portal)
サブスクリプション管理者のサポートを受ける
Visual Studio サブスクリプションでのソフトウェア ダウンロードに対する製品の利用可能性
Visual Studio サブスクリプションでソフトウェア タイトルをダウンロードする
ダウンロードできるソフトウェア

上記「ダウンロードできるソフトウェア」ページにリンクのあるこちらのExcelシートに **Soap Toolkit 2.0** が記載されており、どの製品やライセンスを持っていれば入手できるかチェックで示されています。(なおSoap Toolkit 3.0も記載されています)
[ソフトウェア ダウンロードの一覧](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/subscriptions/software-download-list)

---

SOAP Toolkit 2.0でのWebサービス構築方法やFAQと思われる記事がこちら。
[Building Secure Web Services with Microsoft SOAP Toolkit 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995772(v=msdn.10))
[Microsoft SOAP Toolkit Version 2.0 FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995780(v=msdn.10))

Comment: kunifさんの回答の通り、サブスクライバーダウンロードに2.0および3.0が掲載されていることを確認しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。サブスクリプションは契約していない為、あきらめるしかなさそうですね。